# How to clear lines after the last regex match

Tags: regex, notepad++

I got an huge log of records I need to turn into a table. 
Each line has a record, preceded by date and time, something like this:

```
27/11/2019 16:35 - i don't need this  
28/11/2019 17:25 - don't need this either 
30/11/2019 11:33 - stuff i'm looking for
01/12/2019 08:11 - stuff that i'm also looking for 
03/11/2019 09:39 - don't need this
```

I want to completely clear the file from all the lines that I don't need.
I'm able to clear most of the lines that I don't want if I use the following regex and substitution patterns (in notepad++, using the flag in which dot matches newline):

`.+?(?<datetime>[\d\/]+\s[\d:]+)\s-\s(?<mystuff>stuff[^\n]+)`

`'${datetime};${mystuff}`

However, I can't clear the lines after the last match. How could I do so?

Comment: How do you decide what lines to keep?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing any kind of pattern with the lines that you want to capture. Is it just within a certain date range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

**Find What**:      `^(?:.+?([\d/]+\h[\d:]+)\h-\h(stuff.*)|.*\R?)` 
**Replace With**: `(?{1}$1;$2)`

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `(?:.+?([\d/]+\h[\d:]+)\h-\h(stuff.*)|.*\R?)` - match either

  - `.+?` - any 1+ chars, as few as possible
  - `([\d/]+\h[\d:]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits or `/`, a horizontal whitespace, one or more digits or `:`
  - `\h-\h` - a horizontal whitespace, `-` and a hor. whitespace
  - `(stuff.*)` - Group 2: `stuff` and the rest of the line
- `|` - or

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars
  - `\R?` - an optional line break sequence.

The `(?{1}$1;$2)` replacement pattern only replaces with `$1;$2` if Group 1 matches.

See the Notepad++ demo:

[image]